# What is FFMPEG? How can I use it for fomat conversion?

Tags: video, converters, avi, yuv

How can I use it to convert yuv files to avi files? And back. I am currenlty working on a project that needs to process a yuv video into matlab. I only know how to load an avi file by using mmreader. Is there any other way to read yuv files in Matlab?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @SLaks Well guess what...

Comment: @SLaks I'm completely new to FFmmpeg. I just come across it while reading existing questions involving yuv to avi conversion. How do I use it? Is it a software of some sort. Forgive me. I already checked out the website and all that it is giving me are the codes needed for conversion.

Comment: or should I use cmd? i'm totally new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is FFMPEG? Start with [FFMPEG home page](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

The most common format is YUV4:2:0 planar 8-bit (YUV420p). For yuv to uncompressed avi conversion use command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -s 352x288  -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -i
in.yuv -sameq out.avi
```

where framesize is set with `-s 352x288`

And for avi to yuv conversion use command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -o out.yuv
```

Converts any input to 420 planar yuv.